# How to encode ä/ö/ü in vCards

Tags: php, unicode, vcf-vcard

I got a little problem and, tbh, i have no idea how to solve it. Google was already tortured by me.

So i need to code a script in PHP which is able to create QRCodes. Mainly for vCards. The script is currently working fine (almost), im using this library: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

The code for creating the card is pretty simple:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);

include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
define('CRLF', "\r\n");

$text = "BEGIN:VCARD".CRLF;
$text .= "VERSION:4.0".CRLF;

foreach($_POST as $k => $p) {
    print_r($k);
    echo ":";
    print_r($p);
    echo "<br>";
    $text .= $k.":".utf8_encode($p).CRLF;
}

$text .= "END:VCARD";
htmlentities($text);
str_replace(",", "\\,", $text);

QRcode::png($text, "/srv/www/htdocs/xxx/QRCode/files/qrcode.png", QR_ECLEVEL_M, 4, 2, true);

echo '<img src="files/qrcode.png">';
```

So, the QRcode is printed properly and is saved to the file i specified, this is not the problem. The output of `$text` is the following:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
FN:Mathias Rokar
TEL:015158874391
EMAIL:mathiasrokar@gmx.de
URL:mathias-rokar.de
ADR;HOME:Ährenstraße 6;München;68475;DE
END:VCARD
```

Everything gets well coded into the .php file, but if i scan the QRcode, the `ü`, `ß` and the `Ä` just become nonsense. The RFC 6350 says the every vCard since Version 3.0 uses utf-8 so there shouldnt be any problems ... neither `utf8-encode` nor `htmlentities()` worked. Anybody got a solution for that?

E: This is just testcode without securitychecks. Pls, you shouldnt care about that, it will be done in the final version.

Comment: What encoding is your output in? Did you verify that it is UTF-8?